# How do I call an event method from a different method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to run a method from inside a different method.

This is the method I want to call/run.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried just calling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call an event method directly, but it's generally considered poor practice to do so.

Move the shared code out of that event method, into a separate method that can be called from wherever you happen to need it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeActionsToPerform();
}

private void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    SomeActionsToPerform();
}

private void SomeActionsToPerform()
{
    // code that needs to be run from several places
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For decoupling reason i would recommend to invoke the click event rather than calling the specific method.
Apart from that it is very common to have no logic in the event handlers method to be able to call the logic easily.